# NavigationView lag with network Image using Glide

Tags: android, performance, navigationview, android-glide

I have an activity with a viewpager displaying three fragments. The third fragment is a basic recyclerview using a grid layout manager.
The grid items are basic image and title items nothing complex and I am using Glide to load images.

The problem is this, when I try opening/closing the NavigationView drawer when on this page, it lags very badly.

This is what I've noticed, the lag only happens when I load an image from a url. Local drawables are fine, and the drawer opens smoothly. I'm at a loss and have no idea where to look anymore.

I would post code, but I am not sure which part to post. If you need to see some portion, please ask and I'll do so. Moreover I feel it's not from the code.

UPDATE:

I continued debugging and decided to test the same code using Picasso. This time, it works perfectly, there is no lag at all and it works like it should. No idea why. I am going to raise a ticket on Glide's github.

[image: Fragment in question]

Answer (score 0):

After hours more of debugging and even trying to use Fresco (usage sucks),
I finally solved the problem.

I had to use `dontTransform()`. Apparently, this is affecting all pages where I have large images like grids. This solved the problem for me.